# How to add Youtube trending videos to my app?

Tags: android

i am currently working on an app where i want to display something like a recycle view containing a list of 10 currently trending videos on YouTube. I know i would have to work with YouTube Data API but i don't see what i need to pass in as parameters in order to get a response with trending videos. I have already made an account to get the YouTube API and all but i don't know what to do from there. I have already installed all of the libraries and created an api key as well. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list

Seems to me that you need to make a get request to this address:

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos
```

and set the following parameters.

```
parameters.put("chart", "mostPopular");
parameters.put("regionCode", "US");
parameters.put("videoCategoryId", "");
```

[copied from the Java snippet when selecting the use case "list (most popular videos)"]

This is from the documentation as well:

> This example retrieves a list of YouTube's most popular videos. The regionCode parameter identifies the country for which you are retrieving videos. The sample code is set to default to return the most popular videos in the United States. You could also use the videoCategoryId parameter to retrieve the most popular videos in a particular category.

This is how you get trending videos for the US region.